# Google indexing unwanted pages with facebook app id

Tags: facebook, api, codeigniter, url

I'm not sure where to ask for help for this if it's not the place, please let me know where.

I recently noticed that I have pages indexed in Google that doesn't have any content and it's using an actual page but it's just adding Facebook information from my like button (I think) here is an example of the wrong link.

http://mywebsite.com/nhl_schedule/team/Colorado&send=false&layout=standard&width=265&show_faces=false&action=like&colorscheme=light&font=arial&height=23&appId=myfacebookappidhere

here is the good link.

http://mywebsite.com/nhl_schedule/team/Colorado

So what id like to do is remove those pages from google's index but every page i have as this and newly added page to  so i don't wan't to have to use a robots.txt for everylink I have on my page.

In case it's important i'm using CodeIgniter I'm guessing there might be a setting in CI that could be causing this.

Any help is appreciated Thanks.

PS : I'm guessing that somewhere these links are created since google is indexing them but I can found them on these pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to remove the URLs in the webmaster tools and redirect every link that are too long to a error 404 page